# Android Java programming error while switching screens

Tags: java, android

As mentioned in title, I face an error when I compile and try to run the following program in my phone.

Code:

(File mainActivity.java)

```
package com.game.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void VillageOnClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VillageView.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

(File VillageView.java)

```
package com.game.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class VillageView extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.village_view);
  }
}
```

(File main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">        
    <Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="village"
      android:onClick="VillageOnClick"/>      
    <Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="research"/>
    <Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="battle"/>
  </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

(File village_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center">   
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">       
    <Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Button"/>
  </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Note:I write, compile, install and run the app on my android phone only using an app.

Note2: both the xml files are located in res/layout and most probable are not the cause of the error.

Note3: I do not understand Intent. Knowledge about the same is always appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
PS. Suggestions and change in format of code is always accepted happily.

Madworks.

Comment: If you want people to take the time to provide a decent answer then take the time to provide a decent question. Make it readable and include all info. You haven't said what the error is.

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html to know more about intent

Comment: @TedTrippin, I have mentioned the intent(not Intent) of the program in the starting and have also said that i am unable to find logs since I do all the work on my phone

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the `View` in the `VillageOnClick`

```
public void VillageOnClick(View v)    {   

 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VillageView.class);
 startActivity(intent); 

  }
```

Comment: View seems to be unrecognised by the compiler. Do I need to import something?